# Cannot input some characters using linux compose key in Emacs GUI

Tags: characters

I'm trying to write some exotic characters, like ĵ, ĉ or ŭ. I am using a qwerty US keyboard layout on a GNU linux machine, and I set up my compose key with `setxkbmap -layout us -option compose:ralt`. This works flawlessly almost everywhere, including when using Emacs from a terminal with `emacs -q -nw`. I can write words like "ĵaŭdo" ("thursday" in Esperanto), no problem at all.

But when I try to input the compose sequence corresponding to one of those characters using Emacs in GUI mode with `emacs -q`, nothing happens. Clearly, Emacs GUI understands my compose key, as I can use it to write french characters like "déjà". Furthermore, it does not seem to be a character set issue: If I write "ĵaŭdo" in a text file, and open this file from Emacs GUI, it renders those characters just fine.

Does anybody know what is going here? (`emacs --version` GNU Emacs 28.1)

Comment: What does `C-h k` say when you give it one of the character that don’t work? Also, you’re not using an input method so that tag isn’t appropriate.

Comment: @db48x I changed the tag to `characters`, thank you for letting me know. 

When I input `C-h k`, I see the prompt in the minibuffer after `Describe the following key, mouse click, or menu item:`. When I input `compose ^ j`, absolutely nothing happens, the prompts remains waiting. It's like I had input nothing. If I input `compose ^ e`, then the minibuffer immediately shows me `ê is undefined`.

Comment: Sounds like it’s a prefix character. Type it and then type `C-h` and it will show you what keymap it is a prefix for. Include that information in your question; it’ll probably be helpful.

Comment: @db48x Again, when I press `compose ^ j` or `compose u u`, then `C-h`, it behaves like I had input nothing, and just pressed `C-h` alone (it opens the help prompt in the minibuffer). It does not open a panel like when I type `C-x C-h`. This is very weird

Comment: In that case, Emacs didn’t receive any keyboard input at all. Your OS did something with the keys and never sent them to Emacs.

Comment: Same here. Not a OS thing. Running emacs 27.1 it works as expected: AltGr+ù (on my Italian keyboard) makes the "composing"  ` appear (waiting for the char to be composed with), then I hit `i` and `ì` appears (accent composed with `i`). In emacs 28.2, AltGr+ù makes the ` appear, as before, but when I hit i… no ì is written: the final result is as if I had never typed anything.